# Error al retornar a la aplicación luego de mostrar un mapa

Tags: android, google-maps, eclipse

El código para mostrar el mapa funciona correctamente pero cuando quiero volver a mi aplicación presionando el botón "atrás" la aplicación vuelve a iniciar en la pantalla que levanto el mapa y en consecuencia se genera un error, como podría resolverlo ?

```
 Uri intentUri = Uri.parse("geo:41.382,2.170?z=16&q=41.382,2.170(Esta+Es+La+Etiqueta)");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, intentUri);
    startActivity(intent);
```

saludos y muchas gracias

Comment: Añade el log de error, para ver que error te da al retorno de tu app.

Comment: como comenta Webserveis agrega el mensaje de error, puedes solucionar el problema agregando finish()  para cerrar la pantalla que levanto la activity pero  seguramente tienes otro problema posiblmemente tienes algo dentro de tu metodo onResume() u onStart() que causa el error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no deseas mantener la Actividad que abrio el mapa, agrega `finish()` para terminar la Activity:

```
Uri intentUri = Uri.parse("geo:41.382,2.170?z=16&q=41.382,2.170(Esta+Es+La+Etiqueta)");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, intentUri);
    startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

con esto podrias evitar el error, pero tienes un problema cuanto regresas a la actividad que realizo el intent. Probablemente tienes algun problema en `onResume()` u `onStart()` si es que estas usando estos metodos.

Answer (score 1):

No debería haber un error como tal, de hecho lo que mencionas no es un problema.

Las pantallas en una app son como cartas que vas colocando una encima de la otra conforme las vas abriendo. Es decir, al iniciar tu aplicación pones una carta sobre la mesa, luego desde esa carta abres un mapa (carta mapa) y esta pasa a colocarse encima de la carta anterior.

Si decides cerrar el mapa la carta anterior sigue allí y lógicamente se va a mostrar.

Gráficamente es esto, abres una nueva actividad sin cerrar la anterior

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que debes hacer es llamar a `finish()` y la actividad anterior desaparece de la pila

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando abres otra pantalla (`Activity`) y no quieres que quien la llamó vuelva a verse debes invocar el método `finish()` sobre la actividad que llama a la nueva actividad.

El verdadero error en tu caso (que segun mencionas sucede) no lo podemos saber si no colocas la traza de error que aparece en tu `Logcat`.

Por favor si aún sigue molestando el asunto, coloca la traza del error y así te ayudamos mejor.